# What is the difference between PN- and PM- Differential pairs?

Tags: signal, differential, lvds, block-diagram

I am looking in the past recent weeks in a lot of datasheets and I see PM labels for LVDS (Low voltage differential signals) or generally Differential pairs on the Block Diagram. Altium would ask me to assign _P and _N at the end of a differential signal name, to recognize it as such. I can get behind PN being positive and negative. Here is, how [Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lmx2572) labels DSs:

[image]

[image]

Is there any difference between both of these?

Comment: And to be even more confusing, in addition to the two answers below, some vendors us A & B to designate the two sides of a diff pair.

Comment: @SteveSh I've seen that too! Thank you for mentioning this :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

Some people prefer Plus/Minus as identifiers, others prefer Positive/Negative, and some use +/-.

Comment: To add: T(rue) and C(omplement) is also rather common.

Comment: And some of us can't remember what we prefer, so our identifiers are unpredictable ツ

Answer (score 10):

P and M are Plus and Minus.

P and N are Positive and Negative.

Some manufacturers just use plus and minus signs such as for USB you might see D+/D-, DP/DN, or DP/DM, and they all mean the same thing.

In some cases there may be say SSTXA and SSTXB, but they are generally ambiguous in which way A and B are positive and negative.

For RS-485 the standard defines which way A and B are, but some chip manufacturers use A and B the opposite way from the standard, so with RS-485, never assume which way A and B are.